# How to generate and save random variable names in Classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, jscript

So i am working on a project where i get list of ID's and i have to execute 10 different queries for each id. Now the catch is that, we have a code written to manage it for one ID. 
its like:

```
   DBConnect accDB1,sql1,A
   DBConnect accDB1,sql2,B
   DBConnect accDB1,sql3,C
   DBConnect accDB1,sql4,D
   DBConnect accDB1,sql5,E
```

Now for N number of Id's I need some thing like

```
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
   DBConnect accDB1,sql1,A //A0 for i=0, A1 for i=1....
   DBConnect accDB1,sql2,B
   DBConnect accDB1,sql3,C
   DBConnect accDB1,sql4,D
   DBConnect accDB1,sql5,E
    }
```

Since first we are executing all queries for all ID's and then displaying every thing, i cant display it in loop.
What would be approach to solve this problem.

Comment: Is this Classic ASP or ASP.Net, you don't specify?

Comment: it is Classic ASP

Answer (score 0):

Set your `a`, `b`, `c`, etc variables to be arrays of size `N`, then you can store the results at their appropriate index and later loop through for display:

```
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    DBConnect accDB1, sql1, A[i]
    DBConnect accDB1, sql2, B[i]
    DBConnect accDB1, sql3, C[i]
    DBConnect accDB1, sql4, D[i]
    DBConnect accDB1, sql5, E[i]
}
```

Comment: Hi @Polynomial. Please see updated question. The way i wrote i am connecting to db was just an expression but now i have written how exactly i am connecting with database. Since it is resultset A(0) would be showing 1st row 1st column data of result set. I am not sure If A[0](0) would work here.

Comment: @NikhilSrivastava Have updated the answer as per your question. Assuming the third parameter is passed in by reference and populated for you by `DBConnect`, I don't see any reason why using arrays wouldn't work.